# Asp.net databind to htmlselect with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, data-binding

Hi i know HTMLSELECT element has datasource and databind props. So can u guys give me an example of databinding to HTMLSELECT with Ajax POST in asp.net?

**EDİT**

Ok guys to be more specific i'll explain what i want to do.

**Here's the scenario:**

Yes im using web forms and entity framework. i have a linq query which gets me a list. And this query needs a value which will come from AJAX POST to a static function.

In this static function on code behind i get a value from a TEXTBOX from page with using AJAX and i was able to do it.

But here's the question:

In the static method i need to bind the datasource of HTMLSELECT element to linq query. So how can i do that?

Comment: I assume that this is in reference to a server control on a aspx page. If you are data binding, why do you need an ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

as Bindrid mentioned from the context of your question it sounds like you are using web forms? aspx pages?  and typically this involves server controls. so in the typical scenario you would data bind your server control.  if you are interested in  interacting with your server controls without refreshing the entire page you usually use asp.net update panel.  that is not to say hydrating your html select with an ajax call can't be done in a web forms page (I often do this using web methods or web api calls) but that is not how it is typically done for web forms. below is an example of data binding a drop down server side control.

aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" EnableViewState="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>  
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dropDownInfo dd1 = new dropDownInfo()
            {
                val = "1",
                txt = "one"
            };
            dropDownInfo dd2 = new dropDownInfo()
            {
                val = "2",
                txt = "two"
            };
            dropDownInfo dd3 = new dropDownInfo()
            {
                val = "3",
                txt = "three"
            };
            List<dropDownInfo> list = new List<dropDownInfo>();
            list.Add(dd1);
            list.Add(dd2);
            list.Add(dd3);

            DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "val";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "txt";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }


    }

    internal class dropDownInfo
    {
        public string val{ get; set; }
        public string txt { get; set; }

    }
}
```